# Why does Git's stash commit need two parents?

Tags: git, concepts

Why does Git's stash commit need two parents?

In the [Hacker's Guide to Git](https://wildlyinaccurate.com/a-hackers-guide-to-git), I see this mental model for stashes:

[image]

The guide tells me that stash@{0} needs both A and B as parents.  Why? Why doesn't the stash just point to B, getting rid of the need for C?  I think I am missing something in my Git comprehension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because two things are stashed: the indexed content and the worktree content.  Both are derived from the checked-out commit.  When popping the stash, both can be restored.

Comment: So the changes in B have been committed but not pushed, and the changes in C have neither been committed nor pushed.  Is that right?

Comment: No, the content in B had been added aka staged, but not committed; the content in C was in your worktree.

Comment: Still not sure about C, then : what is the content here that differs from B?

Comment: Anything you changed but didn't `git add`.

Comment: Ah, got it.  I'm surprised that is retained at all.

Comment: Your working changes (tracked, but not added) should for sure be kept, that is the intention of stashing those changes right?  Later you decide to pop the stash or discard it, or leave it.

Comment: Yes, I was used to thinking of a client-server approach--I misguidedly wanted to commit my changes locally but stash them on the server without pushing them.  However, if we think in a distributed mindset, you are right: if we don't want to commit the changes, then we want to save the working changes as part of a stash and it would exist as such both locally and on any remote we might choose to push to.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't **always** require two parents, sometimes it actually requires three.

The following diagram illustrate the simplest scenario, with two parents:

```
       .----S
      /    /
-----H----I
```

Here `H` represents your current head, which is the master branch in your example, and two child commits are created when you run `git-stash`.

The first is `I`, which represents the index at the time of stashing. In other words, this commit contains the changes that were **staged** before stashing. It has a single parent, which is the commit which HEAD pointed to. The second (`S`) is the stash commit, which contains files that were modified before stashing. It has two commits because its changes might be on top of those in I and those in H, that is, they might affect files that were staged or not.

The other scenario happens when you provide the `-u` switch to the `stash` command, which tells Git to also stash untracked files. The diagram now becomes:

```
       .----S----.
      /    /    /
-----H----I    U
```

The new `U` commit has all the changes introduced by the untracked files. Notice that it wouldn't make sense for this commit to have any parents since those files don't exist in the current `HEAD`. The stash commit `S` now has three parents: `H`, `I` and `U` and now when applying the stash commit Git will also apply the untracked changes.

You can see those diagrams and the diffs clearly by running something like `git log --graph stash@{0}` or `gitk stash@{0}`.